# Remove or hide the "all" category in a portfolio

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

http://turnkey.advicemedia.com/semi-custom/

I'm trying to figure out how to ether hide or remove the "ALL" category under this portfolio. The ideal scenario would be that when someone goes to this portfolio page that it starts out blank and you would have to chose one of the three categories.

Comment: You should probably include any code examples of what you have tried to do already.  This helps others determine what help might be needed or spot any errors in your code.

Comment: Sorry all... this was my first question on here. I will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery to your website, like this:

CODE1 -

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

And after jQuery reference, add this code:

CODE 2 -

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("li[data-filter='all'])".remove();
        $(".projects_holder .mix").hide();
    });    
</script>
```

Copy all code

```
<html>
    <head>
        // paste CODE 1 here
        // paste CODE 2 here
    <head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, so that code makes sense and I figure i can just place the JQuery in the header file. But where would I place the other code? I am a super beginner in all of this, so I appreciate your help!

Comment: Right above the end of your html at `</body>`, add  `<script></script>` with the above code between the starting `<script>` and the ending one `</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird question because you dont provide any code or any tag here, so im going to answer it with a jquery solution, as i can see in the page the ALL has a data attribute data-filter="all", so:

```
$("li[data-filter='all']").remove();
```

or

```
 $("li[data-filter='all']").hide();
```

Comment: Just saw the tags so disregard what i said about the tags.